# Obtener el atributo de un elemento html al darle click a un boton con JQUERY/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen@s dias, tardes o noche, necesito de su ayuda

requiero obtener el atributo que se le coloco en un tab que se crea dinámicamente con jquery,
probe con esto

```
$('.nav >a.nav-link')[0].attr('data-tableid');
```

pero me devuelve que **$(...)[0].attr is not a function**
imprimi solamente esto  *$('.nav >a.nav-link')* y me devuelve todos los tabs con esa clase
ejemplo con el **elemento 0**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ayuda!!!!

Comment: Lo intentaste con `$('.nav >a.nav-link')[0].prop('id');` ?

Comment: si y devuelve lo mismo de que  $(...)[0].prop no es una funcion

Comment: yo la he usado como función

Comment: yo tambien pero no me accede a la propiedad/atributo que le mando

Comment: edite la pregunta para que sea un poco mas entendible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente tienes [este problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023806/typeerror-1-attr-is-not-a-function/33023820).

Es decir, estas intentando usar la función `.attr` de jQuery en un objeto del DOM (`$('.nav >a.nav-link')[0]`), y debe ser un objeto jQuery.

La solución a tu problema concreto podria ser esta:

```
$('.nav >a.nav-link').eq(0).attr('data-tableid');
```

La [función eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) reduce el conjunto de elementos coincidentes a solo uno especificado por su número de índice, y por lo que parece, eso continua siendo un objeto jQuery válido.

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: estas en todo lo correcto, muchas gracias, te los agradezco